# Extract Google Group member email addresses to Excel file in Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-groups

I have a Group with 6000 members. I need to extract their email addresses to an Excel file in my Google Drive called, for Example, "ABC". The email address of the Group is `abc@dgate.com`.

I tried the code below but it is not working. Also I cannot find how to get the document ID. For example, I have Google Sheet called "MyFile", I click file and then "Publish to web" then I found this link: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR2V4CUjhfxUQYRZH4DZEJxJma6KMYzu395ShUzD5uqNaX4-pFKe9yMEYVocNOjspJPmUPX_u_kjLNr/pubhtml`. Which part is the ID?

The code is:

```
function writeToSpreadsheet(){
   var values = [];
   var GROUP_EMAIL = "abc@dgate.com";
   var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
   var users = group.getUsers();
   var s = "Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + users.length + " members: ";
  for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
    var user = users[i];
    values.push(user.getEmail());
  }
  var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/dgate.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSoOVdRPk4V23-VHR0-g9ZC-tG6-cFXrioimIIp4jsDrQlUN2iAVuTGA3q-rQQrLl5w79QWvO-LzhEX';
  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

When I run the above code it gives me this error:

> Bad value (line 49, file "Code")

Line 49 is

`SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getR‌​ange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);`

Comment: Which line is line 49?

Comment: Dear Rubin thanks for your response. line 49 is SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

Comment: Here's a clue how to find the document-id: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3STOEukh1pU

Comment: I'm fairly certain that Google can't manipulate Excel files. You need to use a Google Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

On the following line:

`var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/dgate.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSoOVdRPk4V23-VHR0-g9ZC-tG6-cFXrioimIIp4jsDrQlUN2iAVuTGA3q-rQQrLl5w79QWvO-LzhEX';`

The problem is that `https://docs.google.com/a/dgate.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSoOVdRPk4V23-VHR0-g9ZC-tG6-cFXrioimIIp4jsDrQlUN2iAVuTGA3q-rQQrLl5w79QWvO-LzhEX` isn't a valid spreadsheet URL. You should replace it by a valid one.